# Java: Retrieve a random discontinuous Sublist of an ArrayList (most efficient way)

Tags: java, random, arraylist, set, sublist

put simply my question is:
What is the  most efficient way to retrieve a random discontinuous sublist of an ArrayList with a given size.

The following is my own design, which works but seems a little clunky to me. It is my first JAVA program by the way so please excuse if my code or question is not according to best practice ;)

Remarks:
- my list does not contain duplicates
- I **guessed** that it might be faster to remove items instead of adding them if the AimSize is more than half of the size of the original list

```
public ArrayList<Vokabel> subList(int AimSize) {
    ArrayList<Vokabel> tempL = new ArrayList<Vokabel>();
    Random r = new Random();
    LinkedHashSet<Vokabel> tempS = new LinkedHashSet<Vokabel>();

    tempL = originalList;

    // If the size is to big just leave the list and change size 
    // (in the real code there is no pass-by-value problem ;)
    if (!(tempL.size() > AimSize)) {
        AimSize = tempL.size();
    // set to avoid duplicates and get a random order
    } else if (2* AimSize < tempL.size()) {
        while (tempS.size() < AimSize) {
            tempS.add(tempL.get(r.nextInt(tempL.size())));
        }
        tempL = new ArrayList<Vokabel>(tempS);
    // little optimization if it involves less loops
    // to delete entries to get to the right size, than to add them
    // the List->Set->List conversion at the end is there to reorder the items
    } else {
        while (tempL.size() > AimSize) {
            tempL.remove(r.nextInt(tempL.size()));
        }
        tempL = new ArrayList<Vokabel>(new LinkedHashSet<Vokabel>(tempL));

    }

    return tempL;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, there is a `subList` method in `List`.

Comment: And there is `java.util.Collections.shuffle(java.util.List)`.

Comment: @johnchen902 I didn't know about shuffle. If i shuffle my list first and then use the subList method that should do the trick.

Comment: I originally thought you need a *continuous* sublist. In that case, use `subList` with a random starting point...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Warning: This is coded in my browser. It may not even compile!*

Using [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) and [List.subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) will do the job.

```
public static <T> List<T> randomSubList(List<T> list, int newSize) {
    list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list.subList(0, newSize);
}
```

Comment: even efficiency aside (which is sure to be better here anyway) any code that uses 3 lines instead of 30 is highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Nicely done, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using Streams of Java 8 would be this

```
 public static <T> List<T> selectRandomElements(List<T> list, int amount) {
        if( amount > list.size())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("amount can't be bigger than list size");

        return Stream.generate( () -> list.get( (int) ( Math.random() * list.size() ) ) )
            .distinct()
            .limit( amount )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() );
    }
```